# Executing a 32bit ROS App in a 64bit uBuntu OS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to install ROS 32bit and ROS 64bit in the same machine. That it appears wont fly. I then compiled my 32bit App in a separate 32bit machine (with 32bit ROS under a 32bit uBuntu PC).
I'm now trying to run my 32bit App in the 64bit environment (that is, 64bit fuerte and 64bit uBuntu). Launching it from a launch file (this is the syntax: "")
I get this error:
"ERROR: cannot launch node of type [foo_bar/foo_bar]: can't locate node [foo_bar] in package [foo_bar]"

ROSCD foo_bar navigates to the correct path. So it is not that ROS can't see the binary file.

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73873/executing-a-32bit-ros-app-in-a-64bit-ubuntu-os/) by [Mfumbesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5992/mfumbesi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mfumbesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5992/mfumbesi/) on 2013-08-20**:
I have added the set(ROS_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS, true) command on my CMakelist file, but still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is at the moment not possible. I eventually installed the chroot environment and added i386 Precise and Fuerte on it. I then built and ran my application from there.

---

Originally posted by [Mfumbesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5992/mfumbesi/) with karma: 46 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0